# How to position a div on bottom of box flex container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position a div on bottom of each child that are next to each other in one row and expanded to the parents height.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="bottom">Footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="bottom">Footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="bottom">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/xtvDQ/

But I can not position the div.bottom on the bottom of div.child.

Is there any way to accomplish this? If I remove all the box related css it works as expected, but I lose the height expansion to the parent container.

So it does not get to easy: Javascript is not an Option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your css to the following

```
.parent {
    position:relative;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    width:100%;
    min-height:200px;
}
.parent .child {
    background:red;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    border:2px solid green;
}
.parent div + div {
    margin-left:10px;
}
.parent .child .bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xtvDQ/11/

Comment: It would be helpful to mention what you changed here. Fiddle added.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xuscrus/AeRVs/

```
display:-webkit-box;
display:box;
```

May be causes problems.
I hope my solution will useful to you